# What can cause artifacts in highlights when capturing clean HDMI output?

Tags: hdmi, sony

When I capture HDMI output of Sony a6500 or ZV-E10 using Blackmagicdesign ATEM Mini Pro ISO or CamLink 4K (and QuickTime), I see strange artifacts (circle patterns) in highlights and sometimes shadows.

[image: Artifacts in highlights]

These artifacts are not present when recording in-camera using SD card.

Is there anything I can do to have an actual “clean” HDMI output?

Thanks for helping out!